# Apache2 htaccess multiple rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We've built a web application for a client, which should be shown when some specific urls are called. All other urls should be handled by the existing Typo3 installation. Unfortunately, we do not have access to the Apache2 configuration, so I cannot access the rewrite log or change the VirtualHost definition.

The .htaccess looks approximately like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http://example.com/sub/foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub/foo/.*
RewriteRule .* special.php [L]

# http://example.com/sub/bar/year/2014/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub/bar/.*
RewriteRule .* special.php [L]

# Everything else should be typo3
RewriteRule .* general.php [L]
```

However, all calls are routed to the `general.php` file. According to [this page](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), the .htaccess should work as expected. Server is an Apache 2.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `special.php` from last rule. Also rule 1 and rule 2 can be combined into one like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http://example.com/sub/foo/
RewriteRule ^sub/(foo|bar)/ special.php [L,NC]

# Everything other than /special.php should be typo3
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^special\.php$ general.php [L,NC]
```

---

**Update (Lars):** Solution was the understanding of how the `[L]`-flag works. It re-runs the whole loop, so every reoccuring rule has to be written in a way, that it negates the already rewritten parts. Also, from the view of the `.htaccess`-file in the `/sub/`-directory, where I put all the rules, the first directory has to be omitted like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http://example.com/sub/foo/
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)/ special.php [L,NC]

# Everything other than /special.php should be typo3
RewriteRule !^special\.php$ general.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: this does not work for me either - the general.php is always called, no matter what url is used. I also do not understand, why the url should have been rewritten to `special.php` on the second rule - if the first rule does not match, why would it be? If the first rule matches, the [L]-flag should stop the second rewrite rule from every being evaluated.

Comment: `[L]-flag should stop the second rewrite rule from every being evaluated` That is the misunderstanding lot of people have. `L` flag only forces `mod_rewrite` to run the loop again. So 2nd time request uri becomes `special.php` and that also gets rewritten to `general.php` eventually.

Comment: Also try my updated rules. If it doesn't work then provide the URL for which it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't there any .htaccess in `/sub/` by any chance?

Comment: Yes, as I've written in the question, I have to use the .htaccess. Should have made clear, that I put it in the sub-directory. Your comments helped to solve it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you solved it. It is also better to keep `RewriteBase /sub/` in `/sub/.htaccess`.